# How can I access data from the server through APIs using get method if I have the URL and the endpoint along with the request and response

Tags: node.js, api

I am trying to make a functionality of listing the money transactions history of a user doing the payment along with the details with most recent transaction at the bottom.
I have the API structure which has URL,ENDPOINT,METHOD.
I also have the request and response for the functionality.
In the server.js file until now I have written this code. how I need to proceed to apply this functionality?

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path" );
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/static",express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "frontend", "static")));


app.get("/*", (req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,"frontend","index.html"));

});

app.listen(3001, ()=> console.log("Server Running..."));
```

I am new to the Requests and API calls and all these things and I am still learning.

Comment: If you are trying to call an API, you don't need any of the code you wrote so far. Just start by finding a HTTP client.

Comment: @Evert I wrote this code to set the port and res, ie. sendFile, which allows us to send any type of file as response. So, whenever a person tries to navigate to '/', they will get my  index.html page since I also need to make a dashboard. Is it Correct?

Comment: The code you shared is simply completely unrelated to your question, if you need for something else it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Evert Can you give me some reference or some example how I can find a HTTP client and then take a GET request.

Comment: Use this structure (server) to receive requests from frontend(client) to access data(money transactions) from a database(file, sql).

Comment: okk I will try doing this

Comment: @AyushiGupta did you try googling 'Node HTTP client'  or 'NPM HTTP client' ?

Comment: @Evert Yes I googled it but I am not exactly able to find out what should be the correct approach of the problem statement given and how I need to do that. I am very new to all this and very confused what to do I have tried many things , googled a lot searched a lot on youtube can you help me with the correct approach and sequence of steps that I should use  for the exact problem statement and  I have edited the question and written the problem statement.